# JAVA - Set value for field of child class extending another class

Tags: java

I'm newbie in Java language and I'm learning inheritance. I have a question here.

I have 2 classes: `Person` and `Student` like these:

```java
public class Person {
     private int id;
     private String fullName;
     private String address;

     // getter, setter, constructor, ... will go here
}


public class Student extends Person {
     private String grade;

     // getter, setter, constructor, ... will go here
}


public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Person obj = new Student();
        obj.setFullName("John"); // I can do this easily
        obj.setGrade("6A");  //------> Error
    }
}
```

I just want to ask that how can I set grade for object `obj` above but still keep the declaration `Person obj = new Student();` Hope every one help me! Thank you!

Comment: `obj` is a variable of type `Person` so it could refer to an instance of `Person` or  `Student`. The compiler just knows that the instance `obj` refers to has _at least_ the type `Person` so it won't allow you to call `setGrade()` on it. (Imagine I'd tell you to seat 7 people in a car - like _any_ car - as long as you don't know which car it will be you don't know whether that's possible or not).

Comment: To answer your question: if you _know_ that `obj`will refer to an instance of `Student` but you still want to keep `Person obj` you need a cast: `((Student)obj).setGrade(...)`. Note that if `obj` doesn't refer to an instance of `Student` you'll get a `ClassCastException` and thus this operation is considered unsafe and you shouldn't do stuff like that in production code unless you _really_ know what you're doing.

Comment: If you just need a Person object in the end, you could make a Student object and save it as a Student object. Then you can call the method and after that declare a new Person variable and give it the Student-object

Comment: you can't do like that.because the method setGrade(String) is undefined for the type Person

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the concept of early binding and late binding (also known as static binding and dynamic binding respectively).

In short, what you're trying to do is not possible unless you cast the obj object (which is a Person) to a Student object. As stated by Thomas, this is not a very good idea, but it'll work here because you are making all the objects yourself in a pretty small program (don't get into the habit of doing this though).

More specifically, the obj object is seen as a Person when the compiler first runs into it (early binding), so all methods that are called on obj must be defined within the Person class (or a super class of Person), however, obj can still be instantiated as any subclass of Person.

This kind of behavior ensures to a programmer that no matter the implementation or changes that someone else makes in a subclass, these methods will still exist.

Some more resources on early and late binding:

https://www.techiedelight.com/difference-between-early-late-binding-java/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-vs-dynamic-binding-in-java/